# Why Eclipse closes without any error message when trying to import an existing java project or creating a new one?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using **Linux mint 17.1 (KDE)**. I have installed **eclipse LUNA** from the official website and running **JDK 8** .  Now the problem is, when i'm trying to import some existing JAVA project or creating a new one it closes down automatically without giving any error message.

Is there any solution ?

Someone please help me to figure this out.

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: Can you check any applicable log files for error messages?

Comment: No i can't. @hexafraction

Comment: Are you able to use Eclipse normally when importing other projects, opening existing projects or when creating new projects?

Comment: actually i can use normally on a project which i have already created in the first time i opened the eclipse. But now , when i'm trying to import a project or creating a new one it shuts down. :/